# what do "code listings" mean in html ref definition of <figure>?

Tags: html, figure

I was looking at the html reference page where they put all those description about HTML's tag. It says "The  tag specifies self-contained content, like illustrations, diagrams, photos, code listings, etc." I don't understand what are code listing. Does it actually means list of codes in that definition?

Answer (score 0):

It means listing code on the page like

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>Get browser details using <code>navigator</code>.</figcaption>
  <pre>
function NavigatorExample() {
  var txt;
  txt = "Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "; ";
  txt+= "Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "; ";
  txt+= "Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion  + "; ";
  txt+= "Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled  + "; ";
  txt+= "Platform: " + navigator.platform  + "; ";
  txt+= "User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent  + "; ";
  console.log("NavigatorExample", txt);
}
  </pre>
</figure>
```